# Remove image link in mobile screen

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I have a clickable image on my desktop website theme which showed on mobile screens. I’ve managed to remove the image with the following code but it has left a ‘ghost’ link which users don’t see but if touched takes them to the linked page:

In footer.tpl

```
<div id="footer">
<div class="column">

<a href="http://mywebsite.com/delivery" id="test"></a>
```

In stylesheet.css

```
#test {

  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) { image display: none; }   

  background-image: url('../image/myimage.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px; 
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
```

Is there any way the link could also be removed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your element a `display:none;` on the media query.

```css
#test {
  display: block;
  background-image: url('../image/myimage.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px; 
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: whitesmoke; /** Testing purposes **/
}

@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    .hide {
      display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
<div class="column">
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/delivery" id="test" class="hide"></a>
```

Comment: Many thanks for all your quick responses - the image seems to have  disappeared on my desktop screen - so how do I use the code as per Christian's suggestion in my case?

Comment: Simply create the id selector outside of the media query where you assign it `display: block`

Comment: Thanks Sebastion - I'm afraid I'm very new to all this - could you possibly re-write my codes for both the html and css please? Or is there more to this?

Comment: I've edited my answer, now you can put the `.hide` class on any element you want hidden when the viewport width reaches 480px;

Comment: You're very welcome, please return the favor by clicking the grey checkmark on answers that solve your issue, so that people will know this question has been solved. It also gives reputation to the answerer with the accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: I've been trying to do the same to the following script but have been unsuccessful, do you know how the following could be changed please:

Comment: <div style="position:absolute; margin-left:150px; margin-top:30px">  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sealserver.trustwave.com/seal.js?style=invert"></script>

Comment: Or do you think I should start a new thread with this question? Thanks.

Comment: Please start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS doesn't seem properly formed. Try replacing your media query with the following, which selects and hides your link by id:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #test {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your media query looks invalid.

To hide the link, you could do this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #test { 
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Note that this will *override* the `display` style of your `#test` element.

Suggestion: You may want to use a css class instead, such as `<a class="hidden-mobile"...` and use `.test` in your css file instead, so that you can reuse your class multiple times.

Comment: Thanks Christian. The image is no longer on my desktop - so how could I implement your suggestion in my codes please?

Comment: I guess you have been answered by @sebastian-olsen since :)