# Remove javascript link in mobile screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a clickable javascript link (Trustwave) on my desktop website theme which I'm trying to disable on mobile screens:

In footer.tpl:

```
<div style="position:absolute; margin-left:100px; margin-top:50px">  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sealserver.trustwave.com/seal.js?style=invert"></script>
```

I now know how to remove a clickable image link on mobile screens ([Remove image link in mobile screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496160/remove-image-link-in-mobile-screen)) for example:

In footer.tpl:

```
<div class="column">
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/delivery" id="test" class="hide"></a>
```

In stylesheet.tpl:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    .hide {
      display: none;
    }
}

#test {
  display: block;
  background-image: url('../image/myimage.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px; 
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

but I've no idea how to re-create the javascript link so that it does not display on mobile screens. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try switching your media-query to `max-device-width: 640px`.  `max-width` is hard to rely on with higher resolutions now available on smart phones.

Comment: Tyr to put the media query at the end. Cause it looks like that you are overriding the display property with #test css rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the media queries properly by putting the media query on the end as max-width is most probably getting confused of the context 
`

Here is an easier way.

```
 @media all and (max-width: 1500px) {
        .hide {
           display: block;
          }} 

   @media all and (max-width: 480px) {
        .hide {
              display: none;
           }}
```

OR

You can use window.innerwidth() to detect the width of the viewport and store it in a variable say x
And then use

```
var m = document.getElementById("column")
If (x>800)
{m.style.display='block'}
else
m.style.display="none"
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, Thanks, but I'll need help to create the script in the footer.tpl and also the stylesheet as I'm new to all this -  could you possibly show me how its done please?

Comment: But usually it is not adviced to use javascript for things like these, media queries are more preferred as they dont require page to be refreshed everytime the width of the viewport is changed.

Comment: Many thanks Shubham, I really appreciate your help, but I'm still struggling to understand how the following script can be changed so tha tit does not show on mobile screens:  <div style="position:absolute; margin-left:100px; margin-top:50px">  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sealserver.trustwave.com/seal.js?style=invert"></script>

Comment: Hi Shubham - it was something I had done without really knowing any coding - it just worked - so I probably did not use the best method!

Comment: Okay so you want to load a script based on a condition that width of your screen is greater than the mobile device width. There is a JS plugin known as HeadJS. Google HeadJS and you will find what you want instantly.

Comment: I see what you mean - I'll have a look at this info, many thanks